# Display simple html code in post

Tags: posts, editor

Using Wordpress 5.2 and classic editor, I just want to display HTML code in my post. I use Prismatic as syntax highlighter.

In my post, in the "text editor", I wrote this :

[image: text editor content]

But when I publish my post, all html disapear ? Do I need to do something special ?

**EDIT**

Works if I use `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead of `<` and `>`, so I will keep this way

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Paste your code in the "text editor" and UPDATE it without clicking the "visual editor". See the preview of the post.

Comment: This is what I do, I don't go to "visual editor" after